# Having problem to reopen Skype while running?

Tags: skype

I have my Skype running, but everytime I close it, it stay running in background (as it should) but I cant open the windows again. I do a

```
ps aux | grep skype
```

and Skype is running, so for now I use a `sudo kill` and reopen it again.

I know that in Debian the background services can be accessed at the bottom right of the screen, but here I don't know how to access the Skype window again!

Comment: What is your `skype --version`?

Comment: you need to reopen it from the taskbar in the upper right (assuming you use Unity), if you dont see the skype icon there please run `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386` and then restart your computer

Comment: the version is 4.3.0.37

Comment: @Zalgo it works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zalgo proposed, the solution is to run `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386` and then restart your computer.